# Implement TsParticles in an Astro 4.5.10 website

Tags: astrojs, tsparticles

I want to implement TsParticles in my webisite but it doesn't work.It only show me a black background

This is my package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev",
    "build": "astro check && astro build",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/check": "^0.5.10",
    "@astrojs/svelte": "^5.2.0",
    "@astrojs/tailwind": "^5.1.0",
    "astro": "^4.5.10",
    "astro-particles": "^2.10.0",
    "svelte": "^4.2.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "tsparticles": "^3.3.0",
    "tsparticles-engine": "^2.12.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3"
  }
}
```

I follow de README doc but it only show me a black background :

```
---
import BaseLayout from '../layouts/BaseLayout.astro';
import Header from '../components/Header.astro';

import Particles from "astro-particles"
import type { ISourceOptions } from "tsparticles-engine";

const options: ISourceOptions = {
    background: {
        color: "#000"
    },
    fullScreen: {
        zIndex: -1
    },
    particles: {
        number: {
            value: 100
        },
        color: {
            value: '#FFFFFF',
        },
        move: {
            enable: true
        }
    }
};


---

<BaseLayout title="titre" description="description">
    <body id="body">
    <Particles id="tsparticles" options={options} init="particlesInit" />
    <script>
        import { type Container, type Engine, tsParticles } from "tsparticles-engine";
        import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";

        // the function name is the parameter passed to the init attribute
        // required
        window.particlesInit = async (engine: Engine) => {
            await loadFull(engine);
        }

        // the function name is the parameter passed to the loaded attribute
        // optional
        window.particlesLoaded = function (container: Container) {
            console.log("particlesLoaded callback");
        }
    </script>
    <Header dateColor="#000000" />
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="mx-3 text-5xl font-inter text-black">
                    NAME <br> SURNAME
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</BaseLayout>
```

This is my package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev",
    "build": "astro check && astro build",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@astrojs/check": "^0.5.10",
    "@astrojs/svelte": "^5.2.0",
    "@astrojs/tailwind": "^5.1.0",
    "astro": "^4.5.10",
    "astro-particles": "^2.10.0",
    "svelte": "^4.2.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3",
    "tsparticles": "^3.3.0",
    "tsparticles-engine": "^2.12.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3"
  }
}
```

I follow de README doc but it only show me a black background :

```
---
import BaseLayout from '../layouts/BaseLayout.astro';
import Header from '../components/Header.astro';

import Particles from "astro-particles"
import type { ISourceOptions } from "tsparticles-engine";

const options: ISourceOptions = {
    background: {
        color: "#000"
    },
    fullScreen: {
        zIndex: -1
    },
    particles: {
        number: {
            value: 100
        },
        color: {
            value: '#FFFFFF',
        },
        move: {
            enable: true
        }
    }
};


---

<BaseLayout title="titre" description="description">
    <body id="body">
    <Particles id="tsparticles" options={options} init="particlesInit" />
    <script>
        import { type Container, type Engine, tsParticles } from "tsparticles-engine";
        import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";

        // the function name is the parameter passed to the init attribute
        // required
        window.particlesInit = async (engine: Engine) => {
            await loadFull(engine);
        }

        // the function name is the parameter passed to the loaded attribute
        // optional
        window.particlesLoaded = function (container: Container) {
            console.log("particlesLoaded callback");
        }
    </script>
    <Header dateColor="#000000" />
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="mx-3 text-5xl font-inter text-black">
                    NAME <br> SURNAME
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</BaseLayout>
```

Do you have an idea for resolve this issue.

I know there is a new package for TsParticles but it's not compatible with the AstroJS adapter.
I already tried but it doesn't work to.